# Sharepoint breaking inheritance on list permissions to certain groups

Tags: permissions

I have three lists namely X, Y and Z for which there are four different security groups called as A, B, C and D.All groups have full control to lists.My scenario is I need to break inheritance of all three lists and remove the groups C and D to have control over the lists.
Security groups C and D should not have any kind of control to all the three lists.I am trying to create a feature event receiver to break inheritance .Help me out in this regards.Thanks.

Comment: I thing you are mixing concepts. Why do you need to break inheritance o the three lists when you say that C and D groups shouldn't have any kind of control in those lists. Why don't just removing the groups from the lists?. The other question is: Do you need a feature that when activates remove the groups C y D from the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code,

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                         SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["GroupName"];

                         SPPrincipal principal = (SPPrincipal)group;

                         SPRoleAssignment rAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);

                         SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];

                         //The below function Breaks the role assignment inheritance for the list and gives the current list its own copy of the role assignments

                         list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

                         list.RoleAssignments.Remove(principal);

                         //update the list, so that specific group assignment will have the access.

                         list.Update();

                         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
            }

 });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: HI karthik how to break inheritance of a page in SharePoint programatically .For the same kind of scenario as of above i want to not allow two groups to not have permissions on particular page .how to proceed.Any help would be very helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code:

```
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["C"];
SPRoleDefinition fullControlDef = web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"];
SPRoleAssignment fullControlRole = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
fullControlRole.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(fullControlDef);
if (!list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
        list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
var assignmentForGroup = list.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group);
assignmentForGroup.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(fullControlDef);
assignmentForGroup.Update()
```

Comment: Hi nadeem Thanks for  the response but how would i remove permissions of those two groups no to have any permission on two lists .?

Comment: Check the code, it is done here: var assignmentForGroup = list.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group);
assignmentForGroup.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(fullControlDef);